# The debugging is not hitting the breakpoint when Remote Debugging in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

The Debugging is not hitting the Breakpoints when Remote Debugging.
If I run locally,then debugging works as expected.
To debug Azure WebApp We follow below steps.

1. In Azure Portal > Go to particular site > App services > Configuration > General settings > Remote debugging  > On > Save it
2. go to VS and publish
3. deploy > Settings > confg as debug
4. Publish
5. on ribbon Debug > attach to process
6. in connection target put web app url ex: `testsite.azurewebsites.net`
7. click on refresh
8. if it asks for log in, then give credential from publishing profile
9. select `W3wp.exe` and click on attach

In Visual Studio, Debugging session will start after attach, but the breakpoints doesn't hit.
what is the solution for this, please anyone can help to resolve this issue.